# is the orthogonal complement of a saturated sequence saturated?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, derived-functors

Suppose I have a smooth projective variety $X$, and a semi-orthogonal decomposition of its bounded derived category:

$$D^b(X)= < A, E_1, E_2, ... , E_n >$$

where the $E_i$ are fully faithful, saturated (and hence admissible) subcats of $D^b(X)$. Is A authomatically saturated/admissible? Why? If not, under what assuptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. See  Bondal, A. I.; Kapranov, M. M. Representable functors, Serre functors, and reconstructions.